# ngb time picker issue with the up and down arrows

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 4 and ngb time picker for my angular 10 project. I added all code correctly. But time picker up and down arrows not working. this is my code

```
  <ngb-timepicker [(ngModel)]="time" formControlName="time"></ngb-timepicker>
```

my component like below

```
    import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgbTimeStruct } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-profile',
  templateUrl: './my-profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-profile.component.css']
})
export class MyProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  profile: any = {};
  @ViewChild(NgForm) profileform: NgForm;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  time: NgbTimeStruct = { hour: 13, minute: 30, second: 0 };
  addScheduleCheckin() { }
}
```

When  i click the up and down arrows this error fired.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a clue. I know it's not an answer while I need to past code block, so the comments would not work.

The error happens here:

```js
  changeHour(step: number) {
    this.model.changeHour(step);
    this.propagateModelChange();
  }
```

For some reason, the `model` is `undefined`. The `model` value is set here:

```js
  writeValue(value) {
    const structValue = this._ngbTimeAdapter.fromModel(value);
    this.model = structValue ? new NgbTime(structValue.hour, structValue.minute, structValue.second) : new NgbTime();
    if (!this.seconds && (!structValue || !isNumber(structValue.second))) {
      this.model.second = 0;
    }
    this._cd.markForCheck();
  }
```

`writeValue` method is part of the `ControlValueAccessor` interface. It is called when we bind to `[ngModel]`. I can not imagine how could it become `undefined` if this code block was executed.

Let's assume it was not executed. It could happen either if `FormsModule` was not exported either if there is some error happening before and prevents the `writeValue` execution.

I hope this would help you fix the error.